# Выборка из базы по размеру строки SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Как сделать запрос в базу SQL следующего содержания?
В таблице pricelist есть поле (TEXT), содержащее строки с количеством символов меньше 7.
Как одним запросом удалить все записи, где количество символов меньше 7?

Answer (score 2):

1. В MySQL нету функции `strlen`
2. `ORDER BY text<='7'` тоже в данном случае не поможет.

Имеются две функции `LENGTH` - подсчитывающая размер в байтах и `CHAR_LENGTH` которая вне зависимости от кодировки подсчитывает именно количество букв.

Использовать можно так:

DELETE FROM `table` WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(`text_field`) < 7;

Правда, тоже, мне кажется, что она отрабатывает не всегда на ура. Можно использовать костыли какие-то. Кто-то на [этом сайте](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/183791) советовал:

SELECT LENGTH(CONVERT('köter' USING 'ucs2'))/2;

Answer (score 0):

> delete from pricelist
> where strlen(text)<7

в firebird 2.x такой запрос отработает

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение вопроса тут: [Викикак](http://wikikak.org/mysql_viborka_po_dline_stroki)

```
$sum = 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM info WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(text) < 50 ", $db);
if (@mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    do
    {
        $sum++;
        $success = mysql_query("DELETE FROM info WHERE id ='" . $myrow["id"] . "'", $db);
    }
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
    mysql_free_result($result);
}
echo "del = $sum;";
```

Answer (score -1):

могу ошибаться но видимо ORDER BY `text`<='7'